python Email Sender Authentication Failed while trying to login on server
im just trying to make a simple code that sends emails to my clients with a PDF file attached, it was working on June when I created the version 1.0, now I'm recreating using a GUI and the sender is now broken
import smtplib
from email.message import EmailMessage

def Enviar_emails(email,senha, email_cli, pdf_cli):
    server_type = 'smtp.office365.com'
    port = 587
    try:
        print("iniciando envio de emails")

        msg = EmailMessage()
        msg['From'] = email
        msg.set_content("Aqui estão as novas atualizações em relação a mudança do aluguel de acordo com as normas IGP-M.")
        msg["To"] = email_cli
        msg["Subject"] = "Atualização do valor de custo mensal da propriedade."
        fileToSend = pdf_cli
        emailToSend = email_cli
        print(emailToSend)
        contFile = open(f'.\\pdf\\{fileToSend}', 'rb')
        cont = contFile.read()
        msg.add_attachment(cont, maintype='application', subtype='pdf', filename=fileToSend)
        server = smtplib.SMTP(server_type, port)
        server.starttls()
        server.login(email, senha)
        server.send_message(msg)
        msg.clear_content()
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Error: {e}")

Enviar_emails('email@outlook.com', 'app_password', 'emailToReceive@gmail.com','fileToSend.pdf')

When I tried this code I received this error:

(535, b'5.7.139 Authentication unsuccessful, basic authentication is disabled. [CP5P284CA0198.BRAP284.PROD.OUTLOOK.COM 2024-12-12T23:57:36.327Z 08DD19E380D79708]')

I believe that the error is on or the Microsoft outlook account, or on the smtplib config
the account was created today just to test the smtplib and make this code work

This question is similar to: Sending Email from Office 365 no longer supports Basic Authentication and SMTP. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

The error means what it says: you cannot use basic auth. You must use OAuth.
